# Directly setting http only cookie in browser from django (frontend is svelte)

Tags: django, cookies, svelte, cookie-httponly

I am trying to send a http-only cookie from django response to svelte. The cookie reaches svelte using fetch, but it doesn't come into the browser. Is there a way to set cookie from django directly in the browser? Without using svelte? If no, then how to set an http-only cookie using svelte. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this code in Django:

```py
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:PORT'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a http-only cookie from JavaScript (which svelte runs on). Not being able to do that is exactly the purpose of http-only cookies. So you have to resort to non http-only.

Comment: I know that, my question was that I am unable to see cookies returned from django to svelte in the browser. Can I set cookies directly from django in a browser? (where svelte is frontend)